# error with group_by, mutate, and scale together

Tags: r, dplyr

```
test = data.frame(a=factor(c("A","A","B","B","C","C")),
                  b=c(101,103,50,100,50,60),
                  c=factor(c("John","Mary","John","Mary","John","Mary"))) %>%
  group_by(c) %>% mutate(d=scale(b))
View(test)
```

Why does this produce the error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [6]

I'm trying to z-score values of b within each level of c (i.e. "per subject").

Comment: I get the error using `dplyr_0.4.3`. The statement runs without the `View()` call, and `test` will print to the screen. However, `str(test)` also gives the same error

Comment: it does not work for me in R studio but it does work in my base R console

Comment: `str(test$d)` produces the same error and `str(test[, 1:3])` does not. Additionally, `test$d` is a `matrix` in the dataset, which is probably what's causing the issue.

Comment: `test$d` printed to the screen shows `attributes` in the column. maybe this is the issue?

Comment: wrap `scale(b)` in `as.numeric()` and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `attributes` inside column `d`, and `R` doesn't know how to view these. Wrapping the `scale` in `as.numeric()` removes these attributes.

```
library(dplyr)
test = data.frame(a=factor(c("A","A","B","B","C","C")),
                                    b=c(101,103,50,100,50,60),
                                    c=factor(c("John","Mary","John","Mary","John","Mary"))) %>%
    group_by(c) %>% 
    mutate(d = as.numeric(scale(b)))

View(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
test = data.frame(a=factor(c("A","A","B","B","C","C")),
               b=c(101,103,50,100,50,60), 
             c=factor(c("John","Mary","John","Mary","John","Mary"))) %>% 
   group_by(c) %>% mutate(d=scale(b)[, 1])
View(test)
```

This is because `scales` returns a matrix as it's value, and the above takes the first column of that matrix.